# Use a subquery and a custom value with IN operator

Tags: sql, postgresql

I can't really find any answer that fits my question.

I need to know how I can be able to use a subquery together with a custom value with the IN Operator in SQL.
Here is an example of a query I came up with:

```
SELECT posts.content, users.username,users.name, users.verified
FROM posts, users 
WHERE users.uid = posts.post_by 
AND posts.post_by IN ((SELECT user_uid FROM user_data.user1_following), 'USER_UID')
ORDER BY posts.id DESC;
```

This query is meant to show posts only from users in a users' following table - And it should also show posts from the original user themselves.

***post_by*** represents a users UID(Unique ID)

This query works if the user is only following one person. If they follow multiple people, an error is returned. It states the following:

```
more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
```

I know this is coming from the block:

```
((SELECT user_uid FROM user_data.user1_following), 'USER_UID')
```

How do I go about getting the result I'm looking for by using both an subquery and a custom value ('USER_UID')? Alternative methods are welcome as long as they produce the result I'm looking for.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `UNION` inside your `IN` clause as long as `user_uid` has Character type:

```
IN (SELECT user_uid FROM user_data.user1_following
      UNION
    SELECT 'USER_UID')
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 2):

Use `JOIN` !!!!

I find your logic a bit unclear -- I'm not sure whether you want "followers" or "following".  But the idea is:

```
SELECT p.content, u.username, u.name, u.verified
FROM posts p JOIN
     users u
     ON u.uid = p.post_by 
WHERE p.post_by = $user_uid OR
      EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM user_data ud
              WHERE ud.user1_following = $user_uid AND
                    ud.user_uid = p.post_by 
             );
ORDER BY p.id DESC;
```